# HTML5 feature: Server Sent Event on demand

Tags: html

I have problem in which , i need to report browser only in case of problem or success. I don't known exact time when my job will be completed.

I found SSE like periodic but i did not found any thing from google about case 
when the server sent message to client only when it need to send.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "periodic"? You can trigger SSE whenever you want.

Comment: NO , i know SSE is used for periodic . I am interested to know the case, when server sent after undetermined time.